# USER NOT FOUND. Connecting to mysql server from app

Tags: javascript, mysql, react-native, nodemon

I am using the react-native app and trying to connect to MySQL server with correct username and password but I got the error USER NOT FOUND. 
This is my code to connect:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;
connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?",
    [username, password], function (err, row, field) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send({ 'success': false, 'message': 'could not connect to database' });
        }

        if ( row.length > 0 ) {
            res.send({ 'success': true, 'user': row[0].username });
        } else {
            res.send({ 'succes': false, 'message': 'User not found' });
        }
    });
```

});

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to console logging username and password before making request to database and confirm if the same record exist in DB.

Comment: @Neetin Solanki. I did that. Apparently, it cannot find the user but I see the request on MySQL log. I also can't access localhost:3000/users, it says error 404, users not found. You know what is happening?